# WooCommerce subscription hook after completing first time subscription

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am implementing WooCommerce Subscription Payment Options on front end on checkout page.
I made a check box to choose if user want to pay automatically. 
for that I write a method on functions.php file to create a check box.

**Now my question is that what the action hook i used that when any user first time subscribe to the product then it will update the database accordingly?**

```
add_action('what-call-back-method-i-used-here?', 'my_custom_checkout_field');

function my_custom_checkout_field( $subscription_key ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ($_POST['custom_payment_option'] == 1) {
        $wpdb->query(
            "my update query will come here."
        );  
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Commercial wooThemes Subscriptions plugin?

Comment: yes I was purchased this plugin. https://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/